# mac Android Studio 4.1 won't get past splash screen

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have read through all the other Similar questions, but no answer for this.
On my mac running 10.13.6     I removed all former versions of Android Studio  rm -Rf  on all the locations mentioned in earlier posts, but still when I  run the  studio.sh I get the following

The file I downloaded and am installing is

android-studio-ide-201.6858069-mac.dmg

```
    ./studio 
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.542 studio[2014:345964] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.543 studio[2014:345964] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.543 studio[2014:345964] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jdk
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.546 studio[2014:345977] WorkingDirectory is absent in Info.plist. Current Directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.546 studio[2014:345977] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.546 studio[2014:345977] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.547 studio[2014:345977] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.547 studio[2014:345977] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.547 studio[2014:345977] Done
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.547 studio[2014:345977] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/rockie12_us/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/studio.vmoptions
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.548 studio[2014:345977] No content found
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.548 studio[2014:345977] Processing VMOptions file at 
    2020-11-06 10:10:07.549 studio[2014:345977] No content found
    
    plus many other errors 
    had to use ctrl C to stop the madness
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 4.2 and all was fine.  Bug in 4.1 I guess